# Что сделать, чтобы вместо запятых стоял sep?

Tags: python

Задача:Напишите программу, которая считывает целое положительное число x и выводит на экран последовательность чисел x, 2x, 3x, 4x и 5x, разделённых тремя черточками.

Мой код:

```py
x = int(input())
print(f'{x}, {x*2}, {x*3}, {x*4}, {x*5}', sep='---')
```

Выводится:`7, 14, 21, 28, 35`
Надо:`7---14---21---28---35`

Пробовал написать код так:

```py
print(f'', {x}, {x*}, {x*3}, {x*4}, {x*5}, sep='---')

Результат: ---{7}---{14}---{21}---{28}---{35}
```

Возможно вообще решить через f? Если что, я новичок.

Comment: Обратите внимание на будущее, как я выделил ваш код.

Answer (score 4):

Уберите f-строку в начале и пользуйте вот так

```py
print(x, x*2, x*3, x*4, x*5, sep='---')
```

У вас появляется в начале разделитель, потому что вы даете ему пустую f-строку. Если вы просто укажите значения через запятую и укажете разделитель, тогда результат вас удовлетворит.

f-строка, на мой взгляд, в данной задаче - излишек, который не дает удобств, а проблем добавляет

Answer (score 1):

Ещё можно так, чтобы не повторять почти одинаковый код, а использовать цикл:

```py
x = int(input())
print(*[x*i for i in range(1, 6)], sep='---')
```

`*` перед списком распакует список в набор отдельных аргументов для функции `print`.

Comment: Думаю, ТСу пояснения не помешают про comprehension, хотя это отдельная тема

Answer (score 0):

просто запишите так:

```py
print(f"{x}---{x*2}---{x*3}---{x*4}---{x*5}")
```

Answer (score 0):

лол вы че

```
x = int(input())
print(x, 2 * x, 3 * x, 4 * x, 5 * x, sep='---')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Дубликат существующего [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1419800/386633)